# Text Gradient animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to replicate same functionality as https://www.apple.com/uk/ipad-air/ where as you scroll the text gradient changes. Scroll down to "Powerful. Colourful. Wonderful" to see the effect I'm trying to replicate. I know how to do a regular linear gradient (https://codepen.io/laluuk/pen/xxOwxGv) but how do I change it on scroll, I'm guessing I have to use JS/jQuery scroll but don't really know how to. Would greatly appreciate some assistance...

```
<section class="text-1">
    <h1>Powerful.</h1>
</section>
<section class="text-2">
    <h1>Wonderful.</h1>
</section>


section {
    height: 100vh;
}

.text-1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #30cfd0 0%, #330867 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size: 72px;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.text-2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #11825b 0%, #330867 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size: 72px;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i got something like that:

```
    const textElement1 = document.querySelector('.text-1');
    const textElement2 = document.querySelector('.text-2');

    document.onscroll = () => {
        const textElement1DistanceFromTop = textElement1.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        const textElement2DistanceFromTop = textElement2.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        const { clientHeight } = document.documentElement;
        if (textElement1DistanceFromTop > clientHeight || textElement2DistanceFromTop < 0) return;

        const startPrecent = textElement2DistanceFromTop / 4 + '%';
        const endPrecent = textElement2DistanceFromTop / 4 + 100 + '%';
        textElement1.style.backgroundImage = `
            linear-gradient(to right, #30cfd0 ${startPrecent},#330867 ${endPrecent})`;
        textElement2.style.backgroundImage = `
            linear-gradient(to right, #11825b ${startPrecent},#330867 ${endPrecent})`;
    }
```

just play with the precentage math

Comment: Thanks. 
Sorry, played around with it, think I'm getting something wrong.
https://codepen.io/laluuk/pen/xxOwxGv

Comment: i think the logic is correct, because the precentage changes on scrolling, (just like in your link), but again you need to think and calculate the math area. it just too much for me.. but i think i gave you a good start :)